# Jquery Datepicker U.I not picking values when the user select once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using Jquery Datepicker to fetch dates from the user which works fine. The problem is that I have to double-click so that the date value can be captured and be displayed in the text-box.

Am trying to implement onSelect (so that when I select a date only once it should be displayed) but cant seem to figure out the logic.

```
<input type="text-area" placeholder="Child Date Of Birth" class="form-input dateTextBox" name="childdob" id="childDob" value="{{ old('childdob') }}">
```

Jquery Datepicker code

```
$( function() {
      $( "#childDob" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        //yy-mm-dd
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-18:+0",
        maxDate: "0",
        onSelect: function () {
            //
        }
      });
 });
```

Comment: what is your problem? it is worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly specify `onSelect: function ()` unless you have something to code there.

```js
$( function() {

    $( "#childDob" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        //yy-mm-dd
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-18:+0",
        maxDate: "0",
    });
    
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     
    <input type="text-area" placeholder="Child Date Of Birth" class="form-input dateTextBox" name="childdob" id="childDob" value="{{ old('childdob') }}">
          
</body>
</html>
```